# Which Version of IFC Open Shell do I download

Tags: import, versions

I am trying to import IFC architectural files to edit and render on blender. I read that I have to add IFC Open Shell but when I try do that it says determine if my copy of Blender is 32 or 64 bit. How do I find tht out?

Answer (score 2):

Help > Save System Info in Blender and save the file to your desktop. Then open the file in a text editor and around line 15 you'll see: "build linkflags: /MACHINE:X64" (or X32 if 32-bit). However, I don't think the later versions of Blender are available in 32-bit nowadays so it's almost certainly 64-bit anyway.